# Auto Mount of a Network Drive

Tags: 20.04, automount

I've edited my fstab file to provide all the details of my network drive. It works fine, however, after my laptop (re)start, I still need to run manually `sudo mount -a`.

Here is fstab line:
`///192.168.1.1/my_network_folder /home/my_user/net_drive cifs credentials=/home/my_user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

How can I automate it (kind of autoexec.bat from Windows), so I don't have to run `mount` manually each time?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: You haven't provided any details of what you changed in your *file-system table*, my own auto-mounts using that alone with ",auto" option if required (specifics help).  It slows boot down though if a network drive isn't powered (as it'll wait for timeout, so I don't do it for all my network shares).

Comment: added fstab line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your network isn't up yet when your system tries to automount the share. Try adding: `x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target` to the fstab entry.

If that doesn't work you could try adding `mount -a` to your `/etc/rc.local` file as that gets executed rather late during bootup.

Comment: Thanks Bene, it worked!

Comment: Glad I could help!